# How to set default template in outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I want when ever I click New Email in Outlook the new email content contains my template.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you could add settings to any new emails you compose.

1. Go to `File > Options`
2. Then select Mail on the left pane
3. From there you will see two options: `Signatures` and `Stationary and Fonts`

[image]

In there, you should be able to find any settings you want for new emails to have by default.

Let me know if that is what you are looking for.